# aggregate functions error. detail listed below

Tags: python, mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm writing a SQL query to create a new table named orders_years from northwind.orders, showing how many orders every (distinct) customer placed in the years 1996, 1997, and 1998. I'm also Grouping the results by customer_id and sorting them by customer_id, While running the code below it gives me error saying aggregate functions are not allowed in functions in FROM
LINE 2: SUM

-- Create new table orders_years:

```
SELECT customer_id FROM northwind.orders,
SUM (CASE
        WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date) = 1996 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END) AS orders_96,
SUM(CASE
        WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date) = 1997 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END) AS orders_97,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date) = 1998 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END) AS orders_98;
SELECT orders_years FROM northwind.orders
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY customer_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

the from clause is at the wrong position

> ```
> CREATE TABLE orders (customer_id int, order_date date)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO orders VALUES (1, '1997-01-01'), (2, '1998-01-01')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE tABLE orders_years
> SELECT 
> customer_id ,
> SUM(CASE
>         WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date) = 1996 THEN 1 ELSE 0
>     END) AS orders_96 ,
> SUM(CASE
>         WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date) = 1997 THEN 1 ELSE 0
>     END) AS orders_97 ,
> SUM(CASE
>         WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date) = 1998 THEN 1 ELSE 0
>     END) AS orders_98
>
> FROM orders
> GROUP BY customer_id
> ORDER BY customer_id;;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM orders_years
> ```

> ```
> customer_id | orders_96 | orders_97 | orders_98
> ----------: | --------: | --------: | --------:
>           1 |         0 |         1 |         0
>           2 |         0 |         0 |         1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=95a75926997a4e82427a82ac8934fbce)*

Comment: Thank you but I'm still getting a syntax error on line 3 with that code as well. syntax error at or near "EXTRACT"
LINE 3:         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date) = 1996 THEN 1 ELSE 0
                ^

Comment: from your short sample it isn'z clear what you expect